# Is it possible to upload directly to Cloudflare stream from private link?

Tags: cloudflare

Is it possible to use a private video link from a cloud provider storage or from Slack (using user token) and upload them to cloudflare steam the same as this sample public link?

Based on Cloudflare [documentation](https://developers.cloudflare.com/stream/uploading-videos/upload-via-link/), *(but this is for a public link)*

> If you have videos stored in a cloud storage bucket, you can simply pass a HTTP link for the file. Stream will fetch the file and make it available for streaming.
> By using webhooks you can receive a notification when the video is ready to be played or if it errors.
> Step 1: Make an API call with the link

> Make a HTTP request to the Stream API with the URL of the video.

```
curl  -X POST  -d '{"url":"https://storage.googleapis.com/zaid-test/Watermarks%20Demo/cf-ad-original.mp4","meta":{"name":"My First Stream Video"}}' 
    \ -H "Authorization: Bearer <API_TOKEN>" 
    \ https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/accounts/<ACCOUNT_ID>/stream/copy
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, seems public is the only way.
[Here](https://api.cloudflare.com/#stream-videos-upload-videos-from-a-url) it said the server must be publicly routable and support HTTP HEAD requests and HTTP GET range requests. The server should respond to HTTP HEAD requests with a content-range header that includes the size of the file.
"https://example.com/myvideo.mp4"

Cloudflare API only accepts a URL for source, and there is no way as far as I see in the linked documentation to send token and access a private file.

Solution is to have a server you own, download from source and upload it to Cloudflare using their [file upload API](https://developers.cloudflare.com/stream/uploading-videos/upload-video-file/) which reads from local directory.

So the answer is no, you can not directly download from a private server and upload to cloudflare. :/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).